# Issue with Subset when doing a function

Tags: r

I am trying to define a function, which would allow me to standardize the variable. I would like to standardize each observation with respect to its particular sub-industry. The output gives me NA...

the code is the following:

```
standard<-function(x){

  return((x - mean(subset(dat1,Industry=="x"),na.rm=TRUE)))
          
}

std_data<-as.data.frame(apply(dat1[2:8],2,standard))
```

Comment: Please, use the tools provided by the SO editor to include the relevant code in your question (don't attach an image) and specify the language you are using with appropiate tags

Comment: Thank you! I attached my code:)

Answer (score 0):

There are already functions for your purpos - like `scale`. Maybe you can use this one.

```
library(dplyr)

dat1 <- dat1 %>%
  group_by(Industry) %>%
  mutate(across(2:8, ~ scale(., center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Is it possible to ask you if across does not work for me due to inability of my laptop to download the devtool package, is there any modification to across?

Comment: Then you may go back to your apply function: define function `group.center <- function(var,grp) {
  return(var-tapply(var,grp,mean,na.rm=T)[grp])
}`  and apply it `dat1[,2:8] <- sapply(dat1[, 2:8], group.center, dat1$Industry)`

Comment: It really worked. Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. I wish you a great day!